# IIS 8 Virtual Directory Permissions for Linux Folder

Tags: windows, iis, iis-8

I have just added a new Win2012 IIS8 server to my website. The main part of the site is working fine, but I have a problem with a virtual directory. The physical path points to an IP address (\192.168...). The 'connect as' user is set correctly. 'Test Settings' reports no problems. The setup matches precisely other servers on my site (except that they are IIS 7).

The problem happens when I click 'Edit Permissions' for the virtual directory. Instead of seeing properties for the directory, I see properties for 'System32'. I cannot set permissions for the virtual directory, and so I can't serve files from it.

On another server, 'Edit Permissions' behaves properly. I can see the permissions assigned to users on the Linux box. If I 'Add' to add another user, the 'Location' box shows me the Linux server IP, and I can add a Linux account.

I can browse, view, and edit files though Windows Explorer on the Linux server, so there is no connectivity problem. But IIS doesn't see it.

I feel like I missed a step somewhere - any ideas out there?

Comment: Which "Edit permissions" button or link are you referring to, exactly?

Comment: On the IIS console, when you select the virtual directory, there is an 'edit permissions' link at the top of the 'action' pane on the right sie

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer over on serverfault (which is probably where I should have posted in the first place...). The allowSubDirConfig value for the site needed to be set to 'false'.

[Details here](https://serverfault.com/questions/751946/iis-virtual-directory-permissions-keep-getting-lost)